# Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer;

Tags: java

The map function simply iterates through the integer array and applies function to it and then adds it to an output array.  I'm getting this error and I can't seem to find where it's casting an Object to an Integer.  The map function returns an Integer array and is sent to printArray which takes an Integer array.  Any ideas?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Function<Integer,Integer> function = new CalculateSuccessor<Integer,Integer>();
    Integer[] integerArray={1,3,4,2,5};
    printArray(map(function, integerArray));
}
```

I've removed the rest of the code because the solution was found to be the `<Integer, Integer>` after Function.

Comment: Put up the rest of the code - printArray and map.

Comment: It will be great to have the stacktrace and more code.

Comment: i think its because you use generics Function<Integer,Integer> not 100% sure.

Comment: @FooBarUser Thanks! That's what did it!

Comment: thats quava isn't it? it would be easier if you mention it in your question, e.g. add the import in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its because you use generics `Function<Integer,Integer>` guava is trying to cast the values you pass as to Integer but you actualy pass Object.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your printArray method expects an Object[]

An Object[] is not an definition of a "super" instance of Integer[] even if Object is a super class of Integer.

Assume this code was valid:

```
Object[] array = new Integer[10];
```

then this would also be valid

```
array[0] = new Car("Mercedes");
```

But the latter should not be possible. Hence the "inheritance" restriction on arrays.

Same goes for list for example

```
List<Object> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

It will give you a compiler error.

Comment: sorry i should have posted the answer, he said it fixed his issue in the comment.